# Run script as root every 5 minutes with crontab

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a shell script which I want to execute every 5 minutes as user root.

```bash
curl http://localhost/external_ip.php
HOSTNAME=pi.marvinkleinmusic.de
LOGFILE=/var/update-dns/log.txt

Current_IP=$(host $HOSTNAME | cut -f4 -d' ')

if [ $LOGFILE = "" ] ; then
  ufw allow from $Current_IP
  echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
else

  Old_IP=$(cat $LOGFILE)

  if [ "$Current_IP" = "$Old_IP" ] ; then
    echo IP address has not changed
  else
    sudo ufw delete allow from $Old_IP
    sudo ufw allow from $Current_IP
    
    echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
    echo firewall has been updated
  fi
fi
```

To achive this I have entered the following commands:

```
sudo -i
crontab -e
```

Within crontab I specified a new cronjob with this line:

```
5/5 * * * * ./var/update-dns/updateDNS.sh
```

However the script does not get executed. When I call `./var/update-dns/updateDNS.sh` from the root of my Raspberry PI, everythings works as it should.

What do I'll need to change to get this working? Do I'll need to enable crontab somehow?

Also is there any way to see if this task has been executed by my raspberry pi?

Comment: The path you're specifying in your crontab, `./var/update-dns/...` is a path _relative_ to the current directory. What is the current directory when cron runs the script? For a cron job you should usually specify an _absolute_ path — in your case just remove the first `.` ... `/var/update-dns/updateDNS.sh` (speaking from general unix experience, I don't know raspbian specifically)

Comment: Have you check cron record like: `*/5 * * * * ....`